# Clickable cells in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in HTML, with about 20 columns and 10 rows. Each column has a letter and each row has a number. What is the best way to make each cell clickable, so that it performs a JavaScript function and passes in the coordinates?

I've thought of going each cell an id or onclick attribute an hardcoding the coordinates, however makes expanding the table harder in the future and just seems inefficient.

I would think it would be easy to get the row the cell is in, just get the parent element. But I've no idea how to get the column?

This is there an established way of getting both the row and column of a cell?

This is the page in particular: http://jonathanb.co.uk/papers/default.html

I have a list of links and each cell corresponds to a link. I plan to allow reordered the rows and columns or at least hiding some. Currently I'm creating the table using JavaScript, but I think it would be better to do this is php.

Comment: Could you provide code/example to illustrate what your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically get the row and column of a table cell by the use of `rowIndex` and `cellIndex` (assumed that you have an element named `cell`):

```
var rowNumber = cell.parentNode.rowIndex + 1;
var colNumber = cell.cellIndex + 1;
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q2bB/)

-see developer console output-

It should be quite easy for you to add click listeners (and depends if you want to use jQuery or not).

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with my specific web page could you take a look and see how to apply this in a way that allows reordering?

Comment: I don't see any functionality to reorder cells on your page.

Comment: Not yet, but it is planned.

Comment: You can still use my approach even if you rearrange the table cells after loading the page.

Comment: but then say if I swap C1 and C2 columns, the indexes that sued to correspond to C1 will now correspond to C2 and vice versa.

Comment: not if you fetch that cell again, for example with jquery: `$("#myTable tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4)")` will get you the fourth column in the third row.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment? well I understand the code, but don't understand how that will help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23635/discussion-between-alp-and-jonathan)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the table clickable, and get the cell and row index of the target cell that you clicked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>cell row index</title>
<style>
table{background-color:white}
thead{background-color:green;color:white}
td,th{border:1px #000000 solid;font-size:1em;font-weight:500}
th{font-weight:bold}
h2{color:#191970}
#screenDiv{max-width:800px}    
</style>

<script>
function getCellRow(td){
    td= td? td.target:window.event? event.srcElement:'';
    var rc= [], pa= td.parentNode;
    if(pa.tagName== 'TR'){
        alert([pa.rowIndex, td.cellIndex]);
    }
}

window.onload= function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].onclick=getCellRow;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="screenDiv">
<h1>Symbol Entities in HTML</h1>
<h2>Greek Alphabet</h2>
<table>
<thead><tr>
<th width="10%">Example</th><th width="20%">Named</th><th width="20%">Numeric</th><th width="50%">Description</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>&Alpha;</td><td>&amp;Alpha;</td><td>&amp;#913;</td><td>capital alpha</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Beta;</td><td>&amp;Beta;</td><td>&amp;#914;</td><td>capital beta</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Gamma;</td><td>&amp;Gamma;</td><td>&amp;#915;</td><td>capital gamma</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Delta;</td><td>&amp;Delta;</td><td>&amp;#916;</td><td>capital delta</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Epsilon;</td><td>&amp;Epsilon;</td><td>&amp;#917;</td><td>capital epsilon</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Zeta;</td><td>&amp;Zeta;</td><td>&amp;#918;</td><td>capital zeta</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Eta;</td><td>&amp;Eta;</td><td>&amp;#919;</td><td>capital eta</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Theta;</td><td>&amp;Theta;</td><td>&amp;#920;</td><td>capital theta</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Iota;</td><td>&amp;Iota;</td><td>&amp;#921;</td><td>capital iota</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Kappa;</td><td>&amp;Kappa;</td><td>&amp;#922;</td><td>capital kappa</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Lambda;</td><td>&amp;Lambda;</td><td>&amp;#923;</td><td>capital lambda</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Mu;</td><td>&amp;Mu;</td><td>&amp;#924;</td><td>capital mu</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Nu;</td><td>&amp;Nu;</td><td>&amp;#925;</td><td>capital nu</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Xi;</td><td>&amp;Xi;</td><td>&amp;#926;</td><td>capital xi</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Omicron;</td><td>&amp;Omicron;</td><td>&amp;#927;</td><td>capital omicron</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Pi;</td><td>&amp;Pi;</td><td>&amp;#928;</td><td>capital pi</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Rho;</td><td>&amp;Rho;</td><td>&amp;#929;</td><td>capital rho</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Sigma;</td><td>&amp;Sigma;</td><td>&amp;#931;</td><td>capital sigma</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Tau;</td><td>&amp;Tau;</td><td>&amp;#932;</td><td>capital tau</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Upsilon;</td><td>&amp;Upsilon;</td><td>&amp;#933;</td><td>capital upsilon</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Phi;</td><td>&amp;Phi;</td><td>&amp;#934;</td><td>capital phi</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Chi;</td><td>&amp;Chi;</td><td>&amp;#935;</td><td>capital chi</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Psi;</td><td>&amp;Psi;</td><td>&amp;#936;</td><td>capital psi</td></tr>
<tr><td>&Omega;</td><td>&amp;Omega;</td><td>&amp;#937;</td><td>capital omega</td>
</tbody>
</table>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```